# iPad app with multiple views, how do I make ONE single view viewable in landscape only?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

After a supportive answer of miamk, I am a step closer to achieving what I want.. But there's the following issue now:

I have an iPad application that can be used in all four view modes (portrait up/down and landscape left/right). But at a certain point I have a View that I only want to be seen in **landscape** mode. So I do the following in the UIViewController that will trigger the action to view the landscape-only view:

```
- (void) showProperty:(Property *) property {
    if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        PropertyViewController *propertyView = [[PropertyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PropertyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        propertyView.property     = property;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:propertyView animated:YES];
        [propertyView release];
        propertyView = nil;
    }
    else {
        RotateDeviceViewController *rotateView = [[RotateDeviceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabRotate" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
        rotateView.property = property;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rotateView animated:YES];
        [rotateView release];
        rotateView = nil;
    }
}
```

This works fine and thus shows either the desired screen (PropertyViewController) when the iPad is held in landscape mode, and if not it shows the RotateDeviceViewController which shows the user a message that he/she is supposed to rotate the device to correctly view the screen.

So that works!

Then the problem arises in this **RotateDeviceViewController**.. There I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
        [self showProperty];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (void) showProperty {
    PropertyViewController *propertyView = [[PropertyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PropertyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    propertyView.property     = property;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:propertyView animated:YES];
    [propertyView release];
}
```

So as soon as I rotate the device (when viewing the **RotateDeviceViewController**) to landscape mode I show the user the **PropertyViewController**. This works... But when the **PropertyViewController** appears it shows my layout 90 degrees rotated. So basically it shows the content in **portrait** mode instead of using the **landscape** mode (which is actually the way you are holding the device)..

I hope this makes sense and someone can show me what's causing this.

Comment: How are you exchanging views? This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835989/iphone-landscape-mode-switching-to-portraite-mode-on-loading-new-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant workaround (at least in terms of design) to @MacN00b's answer, is to set up a portrait view with a message that tells the user that he should rotate the device and only when he rotates it you show the view built for landscape.

Honestly, I think its ugly to have everything already rotated when the user is still in portrait orientation.

Comment: +1 Yes you are right. It would be a better solution. How do I set up two different views for this then though? One to show in portrait and one to show in landscape. And how do I implement this? =/  (Guess I'll find this on Google too)

Comment: UIViewController has a property called `interfaceOrientation` which is read-only. You can write an if-condition to load one view for portrait and a different one for landscape.

Comment: Thanks. It's been really helpful, but now I have another issue. I updated my question accordingly. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for orientation changes using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

And then respond to those by loading the appropriate view...

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(id)object
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.view = self.portraitView;
    }
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.view = self.landscapeView;
    }
}
```

If this is going into a dedicate UIView subclass for the screen in question you can make the portraitView contain a label notifying the user to rotate the screen to view the content and then make the landscape view contain your actual content.

I currently do this in an app and both views are contained in a single nib.  Just be sure you set the orientation on the view properties in IB appropriately for each view...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1. Jules explicitly stated that overriding this method does not provide the solution he asked for.

Comment: Indeed, as I said this is exactly the same as I have in my code like I said above. But this just **prevents** the view from rotating to Portrait mode. But if the viewer is already in portrait mode, it does not rotate the view.